# Initializing a reference in a headerfile c++

Tags: c++, reference, header

I am trying to have my constructor receive a reference to an object and store it in a private variable. I cant get a initiation list to work. 
This is the headerfile:

```
private:
  Game &game;

public:     
  Player(Game & g): game(g);
```

Is using a initiation list the best way and what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's not working?  Are you getting compiler errors?  Is it failing at runtime?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor initializer list is not just the "best" way to do it. It is the *only* way to do it.

Constructor initializer list is a part of constructor *definition*. This means that once you started to specify the initializer list, you have to supply the full definition for your constructor, including the body

```
public:     
  Player(Game &g): game(g)
    {}
```

If your constructor does not have anything else to do, the body will be empty (as in the example above). But you have to specify the body in any case.

Comment: It solves my problem, but another one appears. "invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Game’". Any idea without looking at the code?

Comment: You probably have not included Game.h :)

Comment: I have included it! Could it be because of my "class game;" at the beginning of the header-file?

Comment: @Dan Andreasson: The only idea that can be derived from this "without looking at the code" is that your type `Game` is incomplete, as the error message suggests.